# Tray icons dissapeared ubuntu 15.10

Tags: unity, icons, skype, dropbox, system-tray

I am currently using Ubuntu 15.10 and I'm experiencing some issues related to tray icons not appearing in the top right corner. For example, programs such as Skype or Dropbox initiate on startup, as i can see the process is running, but nonetheless their tray icons do not appear.

[image: picture1]

I'm posting on this board to see if anyone has faced the same issue and to see if there's a solution to this.

Thanks